# Associating Sentences with Animations

Tags: sentences

Let's say you're teaching someone the sentence "I got in the car". This is a tricky sentence for beginners since they might ask: eh, what did you get in the car? Such sentences are easier to teach when there is a context associated with the sentence. That is, if you see someone getting into a car.

So, I'm wondering if any of you know of a tool or database which can be used to generate pictures or animations based on simple sentences.

Google Images does not help when you enter "I got in the car" into its search engine. However, if you enter "enter car" you do get some useful matches.

But perhaps someone has developed software that you know about which can generate animations and or images by inferring the meaning associated with the sentence.

Comment: The closest I think the field of *linguistics* gets to what you are asking is probably ***BlissSymbolics***. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blissymbols), **•** [Homepage](http://www.blissymbolics.org/)) It was an attempt to create a universal written language independent from any spoken language using intuitive icons to represent everything.